# It seems that these profiles belong to the same person

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, user-accounts

After reading this question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496681/calculate-the-moving-average-across-binary-files

I had a strong sense of deja vu. Gooling for some code in the question led me to these other questions:

- [How to replace values by NA in file 2 correspond to specified values in file 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197759/how-to-replace-values-by-na-in-file-2-correspond-to-specified-values-in-file-1)
- [How to calculate the averages of a variable in several binary files based on classes in another binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342787/how-to-calculate-the-averages-of-a-variable-in-several-binary-files-based-on-cla)

The style, type of data, and titles of the questions a very similar, leading me to believe this is actually a single person. My questions are:

- Can it be verified these accounts belong to the same person, .e.g using ip-address?
- Can these accounts be merged, or is it fine to let them co-exist.

Comment: Just flag one of the posts for moderator attention and use a custom message to explain the situation. If there is anything which needs moderator involvement, they will take care of it.

Comment: Those three questions don't really look anything like each other.

Comment: @animuson The similarities are a little subtle unless you're (a) familiar with R and (b) following the R tag regularly. I agree that they are not exactly the same, but I also agree with Paul that they are likely from the same person (or people, working on the same project).

Comment: IPs reveal a nice little group of very similar users who all tend to ask bad R questions.  Downvoters are definitely wrong here.  No sign of vote fraud, but possible quality ban avoidance.

Comment: Why did it get all the downvotes in the first place? Weird. If it's for not knowing that you can better flag in this situation...that's not all that obvious.

Comment: That is how the system works on meta, I proposed something and people can down/upvote if they disagree or agree with me.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: No evidence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all: having more than one account is *not prohibited*, but using multiple accounts to commit voting fraud or evade bans *is*. So, as long as those accounts do not interact (answering one another's questions, etc) there is *nothing wrong* here.

As such, you also don't need to leave a public comment asking the person if they are using multiple accounts.

Beyond throwing peanuts from the gallery, there is nothing we can do here on Meta. If there is an issue here, then that is something for the moderators to suss out. Flag a post on one of the accounts, present your evidence and move on.

Comment: I *like* peanuts.